# Why am I not getting the full health regeneration bonus from my follower?

Tags: diablo-iii

I'm in nightmare and I decided the Templar's second tier skill **Loyalty** is better than the alternative, so I retrained him. The description claims it will provide 75 health/sec, but every time I'm hurt I can clearly see I'm only gaining ~52 health/sec... and that's with *my* health gain as well!

Why am I not gaining 75+ health/sec?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The follower's Loyalty bonus is listed sa X / Second, but all Health Regen in Diablo 3 ticks faster than that - so you're actually getting 2 ticks per second (which equal 75 in total) rather than 75 every other tick.

Comment: Oh :/ So I guess someone would have to pull out a stopwatch to figure this out? Odd that Blizzard would phrase things in such a way..